# Проблема с дизайном в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Столкнулся с проблемой по *PyQt5*. Когда создаю дизайн приложения в *Qt Designer* всё выглядит нормально и вполне приглядно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоит мне запустить дизайн через программу всплывает нечто похожее на мой дизайн, но выглядящее гораздо хуже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен, если посоветуете пути исправления данного недоразумения. Мне просто интересно, что могло повлечь такие изменения.

файл дизайна **`.ui`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>949</width>
    <height>643</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horLay1" stretch="0,0,0,0,0,0">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeConstraint">
          <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="check_class">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>110</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Показать</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>оценки</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QComboBox" name="class_box">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>250</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="class_lab">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="lineWidth">
            <number>1</number>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>класса по </string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QComboBox" name="subject_box">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>16000000</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>5</width>
             <height>0</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>5</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>:</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="error_lab">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>10</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ученик не найден</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horLay3">
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Показать оценки с</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="start_date">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="dateTime">
            <datetime>
             <hour>0</hour>
             <minute>0</minute>
             <second>0</second>
             <year>2020</year>
             <month>9</month>
             <day>1</day>
            </datetime>
           </property>
           <property name="displayFormat">
            <string>dd-MM-yyyy</string>
           </property>
           <property name="calendarPopup">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>до</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="finish_date">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="dateTime">
            <datetime>
             <hour>0</hour>
             <minute>0</minute>
             <second>0</second>
             <year>2020</year>
             <month>10</month>
             <day>1</day>
            </datetime>
           </property>
           <property name="displayFormat">
            <string>dd-MM-yyyy</string>
           </property>
           <property name="calendarPopup">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horLay2">
         <item>
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="pupil_name_for_find">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_find_pupil">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Найти</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTableWidget" name="table_puplis"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horLay_5">
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_sort">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Отсортировать</string>
           </property>
           <property name="autoDefault">
            <bool>true</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>по</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QComboBox" name="sort_key_box">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <item>
            <property name="text">
             <string>id</string>
            </property>
           </item>
           <item>
            <property name="text">
             <string>ФИО</string>
            </property>
           </item>
           <item>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Среднему баллу</string>
            </property>
           </item>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horLay4">
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_delete_pupil">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Удалить ученика</string>
           </property>
           <property name="shortcut">
            <string>Del</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_add_pupil">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Добавить ученика</string>
           </property>
           <property name="shortcut">
            <string>Ctrl++</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_open_pupil">
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>10</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Открыть профиль ученика</string>
           </property>
           <property name="shortcut">
            <string>O</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>949</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Дополнительный функционал</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="create_bd_action"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menu_2">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Помощь</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menu"/>
   <addaction name="menu_2"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="about_programm_action">
   <property name="text">
    <string>О программе</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="create_bd_action">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Создать базы данных</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

К программе форму подключаю через наследование от класса формы, переделанной в **`.py`** с помощью `pyuic5`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш модуль `.ui` и покажите как вы вставляете форму в приложение.

Comment: Ссылку на файл добавил.

Comment: Форму переделываю в .py с помощью pyuic5, после чего создаю класс, наследующийся от этой формы.

Comment: Можно создать собственные стили с помощью файла.qss

Comment: Ясно, а можете посоветовать ресурсы, на которых можно с этим подробнее ознакомиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня под Windows все правильно отображает. Попробуйте мой пример, если у вас не так, раскомментируййте стоку `#    app.setStyle("fusion")`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(949, 643)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horLay1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horLay1.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.horLay1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, -1)
        self.horLay1.setSpacing(0)
        self.horLay1.setObjectName("horLay1")
        self.check_class = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.check_class.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.check_class.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.check_class.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(110, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.check_class.setFont(font)
        self.check_class.setObjectName("check_class")
        self.horLay1.addWidget(self.check_class)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horLay1.addWidget(self.label)
        self.class_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.class_box.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.class_box.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.class_box.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.class_box.setFont(font)
        self.class_box.setObjectName("class_box")
        self.horLay1.addWidget(self.class_box)
        self.class_lab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.class_lab.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.class_lab.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.class_lab.setFont(font)
        self.class_lab.setLineWidth(1)
        self.class_lab.setObjectName("class_lab")
        self.horLay1.addWidget(self.class_lab)
        self.subject_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.subject_box.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.subject_box.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.subject_box.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000000, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.subject_box.setFont(font)
        self.subject_box.setObjectName("subject_box")
        self.horLay1.addWidget(self.subject_box)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(5, 0))
        self.label_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(5, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horLay1.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horLay1)
        self.error_lab = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.error_lab.setFont(font)
        self.error_lab.setObjectName("error_lab")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.error_lab)
        self.horLay3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horLay3.setObjectName("horLay3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horLay3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.start_date = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.start_date.setFont(font)
        self.start_date.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2020, 9, 1), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.start_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.start_date.setObjectName("start_date")
        self.horLay3.addWidget(self.start_date)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horLay3.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.finish_date = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.finish_date.setFont(font)
        self.finish_date.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2020, 10, 1), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.finish_date.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.finish_date.setObjectName("finish_date")
        self.horLay3.addWidget(self.finish_date)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horLay3)
        self.horLay2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horLay2.setObjectName("horLay2")
        self.pupil_name_for_find = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pupil_name_for_find.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pupil_name_for_find.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pupil_name_for_find.setFont(font)
        self.pupil_name_for_find.setObjectName("pupil_name_for_find")
        self.horLay2.addWidget(self.pupil_name_for_find)
        self.btn_find_pupil = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_find_pupil.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_find_pupil.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_find_pupil.setFont(font)
        self.btn_find_pupil.setObjectName("btn_find_pupil")
        self.horLay2.addWidget(self.btn_find_pupil)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horLay2)
        self.table_puplis = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget)
        self.table_puplis.setObjectName("table_puplis")
        self.table_puplis.setColumnCount(0)
        self.table_puplis.setRowCount(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.table_puplis)
        self.horLay_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horLay_5.setObjectName("horLay_5")
        self.btn_sort = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_sort.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_sort.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_sort.setFont(font)
        self.btn_sort.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.btn_sort.setObjectName("btn_sort")
        self.horLay_5.addWidget(self.btn_sort)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horLay_5.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.sort_key_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.sort_key_box.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.sort_key_box.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.sort_key_box.setFont(font)
        self.sort_key_box.setObjectName("sort_key_box")
        self.sort_key_box.addItem("")
        self.sort_key_box.addItem("")
        self.sort_key_box.addItem("")
        self.horLay_5.addWidget(self.sort_key_box)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horLay_5)
        self.horLay4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horLay4.setObjectName("horLay4")
        self.btn_delete_pupil = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_delete_pupil.setFont(font)
        self.btn_delete_pupil.setObjectName("btn_delete_pupil")
        self.horLay4.addWidget(self.btn_delete_pupil)
        self.btn_add_pupil = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_add_pupil.setFont(font)
        self.btn_add_pupil.setObjectName("btn_add_pupil")
        self.horLay4.addWidget(self.btn_add_pupil)
        self.btn_open_pupil = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.btn_open_pupil.setFont(font)
        self.btn_open_pupil.setObjectName("btn_open_pupil")
        self.horLay4.addWidget(self.btn_open_pupil)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horLay4)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 949, 26))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.menu_2 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu_2.setObjectName("menu_2")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.about_programm_action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.about_programm_action.setObjectName("about_programm_action")
        self.create_bd_action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.create_bd_action.setObjectName("create_bd_action")
        self.menu.addAction(self.create_bd_action)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menu_2.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.check_class.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Показать"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "оценки"))
        self.class_lab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "класса по "))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ":"))
        self.error_lab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ученик не найден"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Показать оценки с"))
        self.start_date.setDisplayFormat(_translate("MainWindow", "dd-MM-yyyy"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "до"))
        self.finish_date.setDisplayFormat(_translate("MainWindow", "dd-MM-yyyy"))
        self.btn_find_pupil.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Найти"))
        self.btn_sort.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отсортировать"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "по"))
        self.sort_key_box.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "id"))
        self.sort_key_box.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "ФИО"))
        self.sort_key_box.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Среднему баллу"))
        self.btn_delete_pupil.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить ученика"))
        self.btn_delete_pupil.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Del"))
        self.btn_add_pupil.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить ученика"))
        self.btn_add_pupil.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl++"))
        self.btn_open_pupil.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Открыть профиль ученика"))
        self.btn_open_pupil.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "O"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Дополнительный функционал"))
        self.menu_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Помощь"))
        self.about_programm_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "О программе"))
        self.create_bd_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Создать базы данных"))


class Demo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    app.setStyle("fusion")
    win = Demo()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MegamallZero если что не так - напишите.

Comment: Ваш вариант не подошёл, но я рад слышать, что на других компьютерах всё выглядит нормально. К тому же, установка стиля "fusion" сильно улучшило положение дел. Спасибо. Судя по всему проблема кроется в настройках моей винды.

Comment: @MegamallZero  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @MegamallZero всегда пожалуйста